# Porque un objeto dentro de un array está siendo modificado cuando modifico otro objeto del mismo array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

tengo los siguientes arrays...

```
var productos = [
 {
   product_id: 1,
   description: 'CALHA MOLDURA',
   metros: '',
   corte: ''
 },
 {
   product_id: 1,
   description: 'CALHA MOLDURA',
   metros: '',
   corte: ''
 }
]

var metros = ["30","40"]
var cortes = ["10","25"]
```

como ven el array productos tiene el mismo producto, pues aunque es el mismo tiene diferente corte. Lo que quiero hacer es colocar cada corte y cada metro dentro de cada objeto, y eso lo estoy intentando hacer con el siguiente código...

```
var productosBack: any = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < productos.length; i++) {
    var productounique = productos[i];

    if (productounique !== undefined) {
      productounique.metros = metros[i];
      productounique.corte = cortes[i];
    }

    productosBack.push(productounique);
  }
```

Lo que espero de resultado seria lo siguiente...

```
productosBack = [
 {
   product_id: 1,
   description: 'CALHA MOLDURA',
   metros: '30',
   corte: '10'
 },
 {
   product_id: 1,
   description: 'CALHA MOLDURA',
   metros: '40',
   corte: '25'
 }
]
```

Pero por alguna razón me está arrojando el siguiente resultado...

```
productosBack = [
 {
   product_id: 1,
   description: 'CALHA MOLDURA',
   metros: '40',
   corte: '25'
 }
 {
   product_id: 1,
   description: 'CALHA MOLDURA',
   metros: '40',
   corte: '25'
 }
]
```

Mi pregunta es, como puedo evitar que el primer objeto se modifique cuando intento modificar el segundo objeto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El código que pusiste devuelve el resultado esperado, como dice todo el mundo. De todas maneras puedes probar a usar un map, yo no soy muy fan de usar for en un array.

```js
var productos = [
 {
   product_id: 1,
   description: 'CALHA MOLDURA',
   metros: '',
   corte: ''
 },
 {
   product_id: 1,
   description: 'CALHA MOLDURA',
   metros: '',
   corte: ''
 }
]

var metros = ["30","40"]
var cortes = ["10","25"]

var productosBack = productos.map((x, index) => {
    return {...x, corte: cortes[index], metros: metros[index]}
})


console.log(productosBack)
```

Comment: Funcionó...por alguna razón que no entiendo, con el for realmente sobreescribe el producto cuando son iguales...con el map no tuve ese problema...muchas gracias por la ayuda...

Answer (score 0):

Haciendo un copy paste del código que muestras este funciona según lo esperado, creo que el código que realmente tienes no es el mismo.

Por cierto defines la variable
`var productosBack: any = [];`
pero cuando la usas en tu ejemplo el nombre está malo
`produtosBack.push(productounique);`

`productosBack < - > produtosBack`
yo tuve que corregir eso quizás tu código falla por esto pero fuera de eso todo funciona como corresponde

```js
var productos = [
 {
   product_id: 1,
   description: 'CALHA MOLDURA',
   metros: '',
   corte: ''
 },
 {
   product_id: 1,
   description: 'CALHA MOLDURA',
   metros: '',
   corte: ''
 }
]

var metros = ["30","40"]
var cortes = ["10","25"]

var productosBack = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < productos.length; i++) {
    var productounique = productos[i];

    if (productounique !== undefined) {
      productounique.metros = metros[i];
      productounique.corte = cortes[i];
    }

    productosBack.push(productounique);
  }


console.log(productosBack)
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero desafortunadamente el error no es por ahí, yo copié mal el código en la pregunta, estoy utilizando ese código en React Native, y a mi no me está entregando el resultado esperado…me entrega el resultado erróneo que muestro en la pregunta…alguna idea?

Comment: probando en typescript el mismo código https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=36&pln=22&pc=37#code/G4QwTgBADmD2AmBXAxgF1gZwgXggbQFgAoCAb2IkpgRVQH0BLeALggEYAaCy+AUw2RgGUVA1gA7VgHIAwgEEAMgAk5EALIB5BQBEAqgCU5UriUoBbXqjgZpx7hGSwwqXrYoBfE2XvUkaRizsXjz8gsKiEtLyyqqaOgZGwRAWVpi2SY7OrhBSUh7EALrExKCQKdY4+ABEAMwADFUcVQAsDUVEpQ5OLli4eFVsDU0ATACsVe0l4NBwfugYAEIgyADWlXgFANzFpgBmThAAFJ0MlXWbEKcAPDM0aJgAdAA2vOIA5qgAFhcMANS-AEpvKZKJ1fLRYIhxAwAI6IXiVcH3DB4BhbHaUSgMXZHJHoKGw+EQACE2FwUL4uwY4l48CB5BBmLxkOhcN4D3KmEqnJRaO2jKoswhBLZD0yLkq4v4qPRjPcGKZQuRS1WDygiAwn0OzJF8IB-Mo8qIO0c4gwsBez1gb21SvmKpWAKAA

Comment: `var productounique = productos[i];` quizás tienes "productos[j]` en vez de "productos[i]" y tienes j = 0 en algún lugar

Comment: Vi que en el link que me enviaste funciona perfectamente, pero como te digo, en el código del proyecto no funciona, hice la tentativa nuevamente y esta fue la respuesta...`Produtos Back [
  {"corte": 33, "description": "CONDUTOR RETANGULAR", "metros": "40", "product_id": 2}, 
  {"corte": 33, "description": "CONDUTOR RETANGULAR", "metros": "40", "product_id": 2}
]`
Cuando le asigna los valores al segundo objeto, automáticamente se los asigna al primer objeto también...

Comment: lo único que se me ocurre es que estas rellenando el array productos con el mismo objeto, digamos: `var productoBase = {
   product_id: 1,
   description: 'CALHA MOLDURA',
   metros: '',
   corte: ''
 }` y luego haces `productos[0] = productoBase; productos[1] = productoBase;` Si haces eso pues tienes el mismo objeto en dos posiciones diferentes del arreglo, si editas uno se editará el otro porque es el mismo objeto